# Filtering by ID and count with Rails AR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a many to many relation between users and teams, which is reflected in my rails models as `has_many through` (instead of HABTM) in both models.

I want to find all teams that contain the user with ID `42` and no other users. This would be quite easy in plain SQL, but I'm not sure how would that look using Rails AR.

My models are `User`, `Team` and `Usersteam`.

Comment: Have you tried `User.find(42).teams`

Comment: @Deepak That would return all the teams that user 42 belongs to. I want to get all the teams that user 42 belongs to and that have no other members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you want to write complicated raw SQL, it'll be best to split this into two queries:

```
# assuming Team.table_name == 'teams'
user = User.find(42)
required_teams = user.teams.joins(:users).group('teams.id').having('COUNT(*) = 1')
```

Answer (score -1):

This might solve your problem. It mixes some SQL fragments, but I don't know if this is doable in pure ActiveRecord. Possibly if you mix in Arel, but that would probably get even more messy.

```
Team.
  joins(:usersteams, :users).
  where(usersteams: { user_id: 42}).
  having("count(usersteams.user_id) = 1").
  group("teams.id, usersteams.user_id").
  all
```

Comment: Why this got downvoted? What's wrong with that solution?

Comment: I just tested this, it doesn't work. `ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Can't join 'Team' to association named 'usersteam'; perhaps you misspelled it?` (I'm sure it's spelled correctly).

Comment: That depends on how your associations are named. if you have `has_many :usersteams` in your Team model, than the above should work. If the association is called `has_many :userteams` then it should be `where(userteams: { user_id: ...`. If it's `has_many :user_teams`, it's `where(user_teams: ...`, etc. You need to match what's in your `where` clause with what the association is called.